# how to change the icon of zoom-contorls in Openlayers 3?

Tags: openlayers-3

I want to change the default zoom-in / zoom-out icons to something like in the Cirlce. Sorry I can't post the picture here so I can't show you guys the image.

Can anyone sugguest me how to achieve this?

AJ

Comment: I know how to make image to circle. That is not what i meant. I have uploaded my example image. please check the URL. That is what I want. http://postimg.org/image/a5c2azbzv/ AJ

Comment: Are you still there? Did you solve your issue?

Comment: yes i m here. i could not solve the problem. But I made an alternative solution to it. It is not what I wanted, but somehow better than the default zoom icons.

Comment: Ah right. Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily override the default css style like:

```
.ol-control button{ 
    background-color: rgba(40, 40, 40, 0.85) !important;
}
.ol-control button:hover{ 
    background-color: rgba(40, 40, 40, 1) !important;
}
```

**UPDATE**
This is a CSS task, so you can play as your imagination allows, so it's up to you:

```
.ol-control button{
    border-radius: 50% !important;
}
.ol-control button:hover{
    transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

Comment: I think you didn't get my point. I don't want to change just the color of the button. I want that whole thing in circle with Up/Down/Left/Right arrow. I hope you got the idea.